# Spring webflux timeout with multiple clients

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have a service that interacts with a couple of other services. So I created separate webclients for them ( because of different basepaths). I had set timeouts for them individually based on https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor-timeout but that does not seem to be working effectively . For one of the services tried lowering the ReadTimeout to  2 seconds but the service doesn't seem to timeout ( The logs using `logging.level.org.springframework.web.reactive=debug` show that the request takes about 6-7 seconds to complete).

I am using spring5.1 and netty 0.8 , I am using blocking with the webclient though because we have not gone all in with webflux yet. I tried playing around with the timeouts for each of the calls a bit and it seems like some calls do respond to the timeout while others do not ( more details alongside code below)

How I initialize webclients -

```
@Bean
public WebClient serviceAWebClient(@Value("${serviceA.basepath}") String basePath,
                                          @Value("${serviceA.connection.timeout}") int connectionTimeout,
                                          @Value("${serviceA.read.timeout}") int readTimeout,
                                          @Value("${serviceA.write.timeout}") int writeTimeout) {

    return getWebClientWithTimeout(basePath, connectionTimeout, readTimeout, writeTimeout);
}

@Bean
public WebClient serviceBWebClient(@Value("${serviceB.basepath}") String basePath,
                                           @Value("${serviceB.connection.timeout}") int connectionTimeout,
                                           @Value("${serviceB.read.timeout}") int readTimeout,
                                           @Value("${serviceB.write.timeout}") int writeTimeout) {

    return getWebClientWithTimeout(basePath, connectionTimeout, readTimeout, writeTimeout);
}

@Bean
public WebClient serviceCWebClient(@Value("${serviceC.basepath}") String basePath,
                                           @Value("${serviceC.connection.timeout}") int connectionTimeout,
                                           @Value("${serviceC.read.timeout}") int readTimeout,
                                           @Value("${serviceC.write.timeout}") int writeTimeout) {

    return getWebClientWithTimeout(basePath, connectionTimeout, readTimeout, writeTimeout);
}

private WebClient getWebClientWithTimeout(String basePath,
                                          int connectionTimeout,
                                          int readTimeout,
                                          int writeTimeout) {


    TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create()
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectionTimeout)
            .doOnConnected(connection ->
                    connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout))
                            .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(writeTimeout)));

    return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(basePath)
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient))).build();
```

How I am essentially using this (have wrapper classes for  each webclient) -

```
Mono<ResponseA> serviceACallMono = ..;
Mono<ResponseB> serviceBCallMono = ..;
Mono.zip(serviceACallMono,serviceBCallMono,
(serviceAResponse, serviceBResponse) -> serviceC.getImportantData(serviceAResponse,serviceBResponse))
.flatMap(Function.identity)
.block();
```

So in the above, I noticed the following -

If I lower the serviceA ReadTimeout , I do get the timeout error.

If I lower the serviceB ReadTimeout ,  I do get the timeout error.

If I lower the serviceC ReadTimeout , it DOES NOT responds to lowering the ReadTimeout. It just keeps on working till it gets response.

So , am I missing something here ? I was under the impression these timeouts should work in all the scenarios. Please do let me know if I can add something more .

Edit :  Update, so I sort of can reproduce the issue in a simpler manner.
So, for something like -

```
return serviceACallMono
                .flatMap(notUsed -> serviceBCallMono);
```

The timeout of serviceACallMono is honored, but no matter how much you lower it for serviceB it doesn't timeout.

And if you just flip the order -

```
return serviceBCallMono
                .flatMap(notUsed -> serviceACallMono);
```

Now the timeout for serviceB is honored but that for serviceA isn't.

I updated the service to return Mono as well while observing the behavior in this Edit.

Edit 2 : 
This is essentially whats happening in ServiceC#getImportantData -

```
@Override
    public Mono<ServiceCResponse> getImportantData(ServiceAResponse requestA,
                                                   ServiceBResponse requestB) {

        return serviceCWebClient.post()
                .uri(GET_IMPORTANT_DATA_PATH, requestB.getAccountId())
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(formRequest(requestA)))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(ServiceC.class);
    }
```

formRequest is a simple POJO transformation method.

Comment: Can you show the service code as well? What happens inside `serviceC.getImportantData(serviceAResponse,serviceBResponse)`?

Comment: @IlyaZinkovich Updated the question with pretty much what's happening inside that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using spring-boot starter parent to pull various spring dependencies. Making it got from version 2.1.2 to 2.1.4 seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: I faced a similar issue, i.e. in a chain of webclient calls, read timeout does not work in the chained webclient after the first. I forced the version of reactor-netty to 0.8.10.RELEASE (from 0.8.4, used by spring boot 2.1.2) and resolved the issue.